# Numpy sorted array for loop error but original works fine

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, for-loop

After I sort this numpy array and remove all duplicate (y) values and the corresponding (x) value for the duplicate (y) value, I use a for loop to draw rectangles at the remaining coordinates. yet I get the error : ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2), but its the same shape as the original just the duplicates have been removed.

```
from graphics import *
import numpy as np

def main():
    win = GraphWin("A Window", 500, 500)

# starting array
startArray = np.array([[2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7],
              [5, 4, 8, 3, 7, 8]])

# the following reshapes the from all x's in one row and y's in second row
# to x,y rows pairing the x with corresponding y value.
# then it searches for duplicate (y) values and removes both the duplicate (y) and
# its corresponding (x) value by removing the row.
# then the unique [x,y]'s array is reshaped back to a [[x,....],[y,....]] array to be used to draw rectangles.
d = startArray.reshape((-1), order='F')

# reshape to [x,y] matching the proper x&y's together
e = d.reshape((-1, 2), order='C')

# searching for duplicate (y) values and removing that row so the corresponding (x) is removed too.
f = e[np.unique(e[:, 1], return_index=True)[1]]

# converting unique array back to original shape
almostdone = f.reshape((-1), order='C')

# final reshape to return to original starting shape but is only unique values
done = almostdone.reshape((2, -1), order='F')

# print all the shapes and elements
print("this is d reshape of original/start array:", d)
print("this is e reshape of d:\n", e)
print("this is f unique of e:\n", f)
print("this is almost done:\n", almostdone)
print("this is done:\n", done)
print("this is original array:\n",startArray)

# loop to draw a rectangle with each x,y value being pulled from the x and y rows
# says too many values to unpack?
for x,y in np.nditer(done,flags = ['external_loop'], order = 'F'):
    print("this is x,y:", x,y)
    print("this is y:", y)
    rect = Rectangle(Point(x,y),Point(x+4,y+4))
    rect.draw(win)

win.getMouse()
win.close()

main()
```

here is the output:

```
line 42, in main
for x,y in np.nditer(done,flags = ['external_loop'], order = 'F'):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
this is d reshape of original/start array: [2 5 1 4 2 8 3 3 4 7 7 8]
this is e reshape of d:
 [[2 5]
 [1 4]
 [2 8]
 [3 3]
 [4 7]
 [7 8]]
this is f unique of e:
 [[3 3]
 [1 4]
 [2 5]
 [4 7]
 [2 8]]
this is almost done:
 [3 3 1 4 2 5 4 7 2 8]
this is done:
 [[3 1 2 4 2]
 [3 4 5 7 8]]
this is original array:
 [[2 1 2 3 4 7]
 [5 4 8 3 7 8]]
```

why would the for loop work for the original array but not this sorted one?
or what loop could I use to just use (f) since it is sorted but shape(-1,2)?

I also tried a different loop:

```
for x,y in done[np.nditer(done,flags = ['external_loop'], order = 'F')]:
```

Which seems to fix the too many values error but I get:

```
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

and

```
FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is 
deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this 
will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will 
result either in an error or a different result.
  for x,y in done[np.nditer(done,flags = ['external_loop'], order = 'F')]:
```

which I've looked up on stackexchange to fix but keep getting the error regardless of how I do the syntax.

any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Did you try to run the actual program listed here? win is defined locally inside main() and is therefore not available for win.getMouse() and win.close() (and main() is even called after these), so it results in a "NameError: name 'win' is not defined" in line 46. Did you perhaps remove something in the mentioned listing compared to your own program and forgot to run the actual program listed? Make sure you run the entire program you list and that it actually gives the errors you mention.

Comment: just a guess, it seems like `done` array is a view (of `almostdone`) and `nditer` can't operate on that. It seems to work if you use `done.copy()`..

Comment: I think nditer is meant for iterating over the single elements in an array, not whole columns or otherwise. The 'external_loop' option exists to hand the final loop off to e.g. a vectorized function.

Comment: tel's answer below simplified it a bunch, and it works. In response to Jesper, the program would run  it was just the for loop that was giving me errors, I might have scrambled where win() was at the top when posting it, the is the first time I've asked a question. I typically find an answer somewhere on stackexchange so ive never posted my own question.

Comment: @Troy, why would that specific reshape be a view of (almostdone), does that mean that all reshapes are views of what they are reshaping?

Comment: @ScoobyDoo Yes, The documentation for `reshape` says of the returned array: "This will be a new view object if possible;"

Comment: One of the great things about `numpy` is that it almost never matters if an array is a view or if it owns its own data. `nditer` works just fine on views as well. That was not your problem. Your problem was that `done` had the wrong shape, and so `nditer` was looping over an entire row at a time (thus the `too many values` error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the `graphics` package (it might be a windows specific thing?), but I do know that you're making this waaaaay too complicated. Here is a much simpler version that produces the same `done` array:

```
from graphics import *
import numpy as np

# starting array
startArray = np.array([[2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7],
                       [5, 4, 8, 3, 7, 8]])

# searching for duplicate (y) values and removing that row so the corresponding (x) is removed too.
done = startArray.T[np.unique(startArray[1,:], return_index=True)[1]]

for x,y in done:
    print("this is x,y:", x, y)
    print("this is y:", y)
    rect = Rectangle(Point(x,y),Point(x+4,y+4))
    rect.draw(win)
```

To note, in the above version `done.shape==(5, 2)` instead of `(2, 5)`, but you can always change that back after the `for` loop with `done = done.T`.

Here's some notes on your original code for future reference:

- The `order` flag in `reshape` is completely superfluous to what your code is trying to do, and just makes it more confusing/potentially more buggy. You can do all of the reshapes you wanted to do without it.
- The use case for `nditer` is to iterate over the individual elements of one (or more) array one at a time. It cannot in general be used to iterate over the rows or columns of a 2D array. If you try to use it this way, you're likely to get buggy results that are highly dependent on the layout of the array in memory (as you saw).
- To iterate over rows or columns of a 2D array, just use simple iteration. If you just iterate over an array (eg `for row in arr:`), you get each row, one at a time. If you want the columns instead you can transpose the array first (like I did in the code above with `.T`).

#### Note about `.T`

`.T` takes the transpose of an array. For example, if you start with

```
arr = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

then the transpose is:

```
arr.T==np.array([[0, 4],
                 [1, 5],
                 [2, 6],
                 [3, 7]])
```

Comment: wow!! do I feel stupid. That is so much more simple. Everytime I tried using unique  without doing all those reshapes it would scramble the x,y values during the sort. So it would sort them but the remaining x values weren't link to their correct y.  I need to research more what T. does.

Comment: @ScoobyDoo `arr.T` is equivalent to `np.transpose(arr)`. For 2D arrays you can just think of this as tipping the array over on its side: rows become columns and columns become rows.

Comment: I see, that is clearly way more efficient than what I was using, and exactly what was needed for my issue. Thank you!